# I can't make a test request with axios GET in typescript. I get a Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm learning to use axios with typescript so I try to make a 'get' request but it doesn't work I get the message :

> App.js:59 Error retrieving data: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

my local test file App.tsx :

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    const { useEffect, useState } = React;

    import axios from "axios";

    function App() {
      const [data, setData] = useState(null);

      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          try {
            const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
            setData(response.data);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Erreur lors de la récupération des données:', error);
          }
        };

        fetchData();
      }, []);

      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Données récupérées</h1>
          {data ? <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre> : <p>Aucune donnée récupérée</p>}
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

my config tsconfig.tsjson:

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
          "dom",
          "dom.iterable",
          "esnext"
        ],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx"
      },
      "include": [
        "src"
      ]
    }
```

I can't find any solutions

Comment: Move imports on top? It seems that axios is undefined so it can not read get from undefined. Did you actualy add axios to the project? npm install axios if you are using npm.

Comment: hello thank you for replying, yes I had installed axios

Comment: it's a test project on react CRA and I've installed axios

Comment: Did you try grupping your imports on top before any other code? It should work if axios is installed IMHO.

Comment: making the same get request test file in javascript the 'axios.get' request works, so it's really a typescript problem I think

Comment: Axios come with its own types, this should not be an issue. You can try typing the response like import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios'; then uing AxiosResponse as a type for the const response. Also make sure you got the stable version of typescript. It is a problem that TS detects but it sounds like axios is undefined. It is wierd TBH i used both before the code I see seems OK.

Comment: It is a long shot but the demo tsconfig I found working misses moduleResolution and noEmit. Those are only differences so you might as well try those as a long shot.

Comment: sorry not to have rep before the problem was solved by rerunning vs code ...